# Iterate MapThread with matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Consider a function `f` and a list `p={a,b,c}`. I want to get a list of

```
f[a,a]
f[a,b]
f[a,c]
f[b,a]
f[b,b]
f[b,c]
f[c,a]
f[c,b]
f[c,c]
```

In real use, `p` can have higher dimensions, and f may take more arguments, e.g. I may  need to generate a list of `f[a,a,a,a]` through `f[z,z,z,z]`. Is there a cleaner way to do this other than making lists that approximately repeat the elements of `p` then use `MapThread`? e.g.

```
p={a,b}
p1 = {a, a, b, b}
p2 = {a, b, a, b}
MapThread[f, {p1, p2}]
```

Here, `a`, `b` can be matrices

Comment: What about `Outer`?

Comment: @chuy Thanks! but `Outer` may not be a good fit when `a,b ...` are matrices.

Comment: Just realized that `p = {a, b, c}; Distribute[f[p, p], List]` works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
Tuples[f[{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}]]
```

> {f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[b, a], f[b, b], f[b, c], f[c, a], 
>    f[c, b], f[c, c]}

```
f @@@ Tuples[{a, b, c}, 2]
```

> same result

```
Tuples[f[{a, b}, {r, s, t}, {x, y}]]
```

> {f[a, r, x], f[a, r, y], f[a, s, x], f[a, s, y], f[a, t, x], 
>    f[a, t, y], f[b, r, x], f[b, r, y], f[b, s, x], f[b, s, y], 
>    f[b, t, x], f[b, t, y]}

```
f @@@ Tuples[{{a, b}, {r, s, t}, {x, y}}]
```

> same result

```
p = {a, b};
p1 = {a, a, b, b};
Tuples[f[p, p1]]
```

> {f[a, a], f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, b], f[b, a], f[b, a], f[b, b], 
>        f[b, b]}

Comment: Oops, might need to be changed when `a,b,c` are matrices?

Comment: Thanks! But when I use e.g. 2x2 matrices for `a, b, c`, `p={a,b,c}`, then `Tuples[KroneckerProduct[p, p]] // Dimensions` is `{262144, 9, 4}`, and does not give 9 4-by-4 matrices...

Comment: @egwenesedai, does `KroneckerProduct@@@Tuples[p, 2]` work?

Comment: Works, thanks a lot!

Comment: you can also use `Tuples[kp[p, p]] /. kp -> KroneckerProduct` (to prevent `KroneckerProduct` evaluating before Tuples does its job)

Answer (score 7):

You could also use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples) as follows:

```
Tuples[f[a,b,c], 2]
```

> {f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[b, a], f[b, b], f[b, c], f[c, a], f[c, b], 
>    f[c, c]}

If `f` evaluates, and you want to do this for matrices, you could do:

```
p = RandomInteger[1, {3, 2, 2}];
Block[{KroneckerProduct}, Tuples[KroneckerProduct @@ p, 2]] //Dimensions
```

> {9, 4, 4}

Comment: Thanks! That's one clever use for `Block `